# How to use Couchbase SDK in Python with robotframework RIDE?

Tags: python, python-2.7, couchbase, robotframework

I have installed the couchbase SDK from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase#downloads with path as C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\couchbase, and now I want to use this library with robotframework and RIDE.

The problem is after I add a line of code in the `__init__.py`, just like:

> from couchbase._bootstrap import *

and compiled with `python -m py_compile __init__.py`, I still can't find the keywords in the _bootstrap.py with RIDE. All the keywords I see with RIDE is originally in the `__init__.py` before I add the line of code, and it seems not worked with adding the `from couchbase._bootstrap import *` in the `__init__.py`.

Does anyone know how to get it? The robotframework user guide doesn't describe this very carefully. Thanks for the help.

Comment: so you pip install'ed couchbase? if so, when you run 'pip freeze' do you see the couchbase lib listed?

Comment: Hi,
I can see couchbase==2.0.4 shown in the list with pip freeze.

Comment: that's good. perhaps the problem is with RIDE, not couchbase (and in that case I can't help you :/)

Comment: Is your question specifically about seeing the keywords in RIDE (the IDE), or is it about when you run your test with robot framework? RIDE and the robot framework are two different things.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RIDE, but you should certainly not import directly from modules marked as private. `_bootstrap` is a private module and is supposed to set up the runtime glue between the C extension and the python module.

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley,
I can see the original keyword in `__init__.py` from RIDE. I think RIDE will automatically capture keywords from  `__init__.py` in packages, but I want to capture all the keywords in packages, and not just from the `__init__.py`. For example, if you import the `pip` library in RIDE, you can see RIDE capture the keywords in `__init__.py` from `pip`.

Comment: Hi @MarkNunberg,
I think the problem is not related to private module. The `_bootstrap` is a example. I can't get it with others, too.

Comment: Oh ok. Please keep in mind that the Python Couchbase client is a C extension primarily. I'm also not sure what you mean by keywords -- do you mean method definitions? Also, the main interface with Couchbase (the place where you actually interact with the cluster) is in the `couchbase.bucket` module in the `Bucket` class.